# How to make eclipse auto completion feature work effectively

Tags: eclipse

i am using content assist in eclipse since a long time. but there is a problem in eclipse, i have enabled content assist and whenever i am writing some
primitive like

```
 String userName = new String();
```

then instead of taking my own primitive type, as soon as i type space the IDE append the reference variable name with something like

userNameString;

So is there any way where i can disable the space bar to automatically auto complete the code and this responsibility of auto completion should be handeled by enter key so that whenever i want something, i will be having the freedom of selecting a specific option.

Comment: Identifiers can't have spaces in them, that's why it's been made to insert the selected proposal. By "enabling" content assist, did you do something like make every character an auto-activation character?

Comment: yes i did. actually i included everything i content assist like .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.